# what is the purpose of require_once dirname(__FILE__) ...?

Tags: php, file, require-once, dirname

I am using a php library which has this code: `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';`

From what I've read, `dirname(__FILE__)` points to the current directory.

So wouldn't it be easier to just write `require_once 'config.php';`?

My only guess here is that including the `dirname(__FILE__)` ensures that the `require_once` function uses an absolute rather than relative path.

Comment: That's the reason - it ensures an absolute path. Other scripts can change the working directory with `chdir()`, which can confuse the include paths.  Likewise, if called from something other than HTTP (like CLI or cron, for example), the include paths may be different, or the working directory may be different.

Comment: Could just use `__DIR__` instead...

Comment: Aparently `__DIR__` is available from php 5.3 and up. Sources:[1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29423749/3258851), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2749423/3258851)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, you are right** - `dirname(__FILE__)` ensures that the [**require_once**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) function uses an absolute rather than relative path.

The `__FILE__` constant  represents the running script. It will return the full path and file name of the running script.

For example, if a script called `database.init.php` which is included from anywhere on the filesystem wants to include the script `database.class.php`, which lays in the same directory, you can use:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/database.class.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

an example:

if your file is inlcuded somewhere then by default it will start searching from the path of the file that included yours. in this case the require will not work for files that are next to your file